# How to change content of a cell in a Table when clicking on that cell

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

I have a Table on Java SWT. I have a "payed" column and all the items have "non payed" written and a icon of non payed. It's the fourth column of the table.

I have populated the table with dummy content, Now, I want to add a listener on the cells of the fourth column "payed" to change the content of the clicked cell. If the cell has non payed text and icon, must change to payed text and icon, and the opposite behaviour.

I can't find the way to achieve that, because I can't add a selection listener to a cell of the table, or I don't know how to do it.

This is my source code:

```
Table membersTable = new Table(clubComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CHECK | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
membersTable.setLinesVisible(true);
membersTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
membersTable.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

TableColumn tblclmnName = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
tblclmnName.setWidth(150);
tblclmnName.setText("Nombre");

TableColumn tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber.setWidth(120);
tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber.setText("Teléfono");

TableColumn tblclmnCommonMoney = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
tblclmnCommonMoney.setWidth(150);
tblclmnCommonMoney.setText("Participación Habitual");

TableColumn tblclmnPayed = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.CENTER);
tblclmnPayed.setWidth(50);
tblclmnPayed.setText("Payed"); 

// populate Table
for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
    TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(membersTable, SWT.CENTER);                  
    tableItem.setText(new String[] {"person "+i, "610610620", "100", "non payed"});
    tableItem.setImage(3, uncheckedImage);
}
```

EDIT:

OK i managed to do it with a checkbox, but now how can i know in which row is clicked the checkbox? I need it to get the value of the third column

```
// populate Table
    for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(membersTable, SWT.NONE);                    
        tableItem.setText(new String[] {"person "+i, "610610620", "100"});

        Button button = new Button(membersTable, SWT.CHECK);
        button.pack();
        TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(membersTable);
        editor.minimumWidth = button.getSize().x;
        editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
        editor.setEditor(button, tableItem, 3);

        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                //how to know in which row is clicked the checkbox?
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why you don't use a button instead in the 4th column to change payed status? (Maybe I'm misundertanding the use case) I think that will cover your case and it's easier to add proper listeners.

Comment: @RafaelPalomino how can I use a button for that? Can I put a checkbox instead of a button? whould be better for my needs. Can you share a sample code using a checkbox and listeners? thank you

Comment: ok @RafaelPalomino I managed to add a button with checkbox style and now I can add a listener, but how can i Know in which row is clicked the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're inside the `for`-loop creating the `TableItem`, you already have the index of the row. Similarly, if you need the actual `TableItem`, you already have access to that as well.

```
for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
    TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(membersTable, SWT.NONE);                    
    tableItem.setText(new String[] {"person "+i, "610610620", "100"});

    Button button = new Button(membersTable, SWT.CHECK);
    button.pack();
    TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(membersTable);
    editor.minimumWidth = button.getSize().x;
    editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
    editor.setEditor(button, tableItem, 3);

    final int index = i; // Hold the row index here

    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            //how to know in which row is clicked the checkbox?
            System.out.println("Row selected: " + index);
            System.out.println("Participación Habitual: " + tableItem.getText(2));
        }
    });
}
```

---

**Edit:**
As mentioned in the comments, using `index` will be unreliable if a row is deleted. Instead you can use [`Table.indexOf(TableItem)`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Table.html#indexOf-org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem-) if you need the numerical index.

```
@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    //how to know in which row is clicked the checkbox?
    System.out.println("Row selected: " + membersTable.indexOf(tableItem));
    System.out.println("Participación Habitual: " + tableItem.getText(2));
}
```

Comment: how to get the actual TableItem?

Comment: @NullPointerException The `TableItem` created at the beginning of the `for`-loop is already accessible from within `widgetSelected`. Updated my answer to show an example of accessing item and getting the value in the 3rd column as your question asks.

Comment: there is another way to know in which button has the user pressed? I ask it because it whould be common the case of deleted rows, so the index you are using whould be incorrect. I tryed with "membersTable.getSelectionIndex();" on the widgetSelected event but it returns -1 because when you press on the button you are not pressing into the row

Comment: Even though `index` would not be reliable in this case, using the `tableItem` would be. If you need the numerical index of that item, you can use the [`Table#indexOf(TableItem)`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Table.html#indexOf-org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem-) method from inside the listener. Will update my answer.

Comment: @NullPointerException you’re welcome - glad I could help!